# How can i add a second y-axis in Google Sheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

Im working on a google spreadhsset with a google-api-python-client, im trying to add chart in a sheet with two y-axis, one on the left and one on the right. After a code for login to a google service,to do this im using a spreadsheet resource and batchUpdate method,the body of request is

```
body_chart_Create={
  "requests": [
    {
      "addChart": {
        "chart": {
            "position":
                {
                "newSheet": True
                },
          "spec": {
            "title": "TEST CHART",
            "titleTextPosition": {
            "horizontalAlignment":"center"
            },
            "basicChart": {
              "chartType": "LINE",
              "legendPosition": "RIGHT_LEGEND",
              "axis": [
                {
                  "position": "BOTTOM_AXIS",
                  "title": "Time"
                },
                {
                  "position": "LEFT_AXIS",
                  "title": "Relative Humidity [%rH]"
                },
                {
                  "position": "RIGHT_AXIS",
                  "title": "Temperature [°C]"
                }
              ],
              "domains": [
                {
                  "domain": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId":814487582,
                          "startRowIndex": 0,
                          "endRowIndex": 1003,
                          "startColumnIndex": 0,
                          "endColumnIndex":1
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "series": [
                {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 814487582,
                          "startColumnIndex": 1,
                          "endColumnIndex": 2
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "LEFT_AXIS"
                },
                  {
                  "series": {
                    "sourceRange": {
                      "sources": [
                        {
                          "sheetId": 814487582,
                          "startColumnIndex": 2,
                          "endColumnIndex": 3
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "targetAxis": "RIGHT_AXIS"
                },
              ],
              "headerCount": 1
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the call to a service is :

```
spreadsheets = service.spreadsheets()
response = spreadsheets.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=ID, body=body_chart_Create).execute()
```

The result is:
[image]

How we can see , the chart appaer on the sheet but the RIGHT-AXIS , in this case, named with

Temperature[°C] dosent appare.

Comment: 2023, and I still experience this. I am using chart.build() and insertChart(). On first run, no right-axis title appears. When I run the code again, surprisingly it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Sheets API not respecting batch update request to add a right-axis title on chart creation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153528225)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.